# LLevar una consulta a .HTML (el final no puede ser php)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

lo primero decir que soy muy nuevo programando (por no decir que no tengo ni idea, así que siento si no me explico bien... o si pregunto una chorrada)

Necesito hacer una consulta a una base de datos Mysql. Que me de una linea aleatoria y esa línea mostrarla en HTML, cada vez que ejecute abra la página HTML obtenga una respueta nueva. (El archivo final tiene que ser .html no sirve .php por limitaciones del sistema donde voy a incluirlo)

He generado la consulta en php y la respuesta la convierto a json (tanto la respuesta php, como creando un .json para probar las dos opciones) Nose si el proceso lo he realizado bien pero recibo una respuesta json. Pero ahí me atasco, ahora no soy capaz de leer ese json en html ni con javascript ni con ajax....

Cómo deberia hacerlo? Lo mismo tengo mal hasta la consulta, este es el codigo que tengo y la pagina:

1.- Pagina php con la consulta y la conversión a json:

[Consulta mysql y parse json](https://pruebasxibo.000webhostapp.com/prueba%20json.php)

[Fichero json que general](https://pruebasxibo.000webhostapp.com/linea.json)

Código php:
[Codigo copiado en sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fac3a3f392bd6d0e25f9e2082d266b1afa834a9b)

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
include_once("config.php");


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM gastos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"); 
$linea = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $id=$row['id'];
    $importe=$row['importe'];
    $concepto=$row['concepto'];
    $fecha=$row['fecha'];



    $linea[] = array('id'=> $id, 'importe'=> $importe, 'concepto'=> $concepto, 'fecha'=> $fecha);

}

$json_string = json_encode($linea);
echo $json_string;

$file = 'linea.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
?>
```

Muchisimas gracias a todos.

ACTUALIZACION!!!!!!!

Buneos dias.... modifico la pregunta, he ido por este lado, y en la consola me retorna un array... esta bien? os copio el codigo:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
include_once("conexbase.php");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM consejosdesalud ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"); // using mysqli_query instead


$row = mysqli_fetch_Assoc($result);
$json = array(

    'unidas' => array()
);


foreach($row as $val){
    $json['unidas'][] = $val;
}

$json_string = json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json_string;
?>
```

el js:

```
 window.onload = function(){
   //declaramos un event handler para el evento load de window.
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var pantalla = document.getElementById('ajaxPantalla');
   var titulo = document.getElementById('titulo');

   if(xhr){
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if(xhr.readyState == 4){
            //if(xhr.status == 200 || xhr.state == 304){
               pantalla.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

               var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText );
               console.log( response );


            //}
         }else{
            //proveer mensajes para los diferentes codigos http.
         }
      };
      xhr.open('GET','crearjson.php',true);
      xhr.send(null);
   }else{
      //proveer una alternativa a ajax si no esta disponible.
   }


};
```

y por ultimo el html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="ajaxPantalla"></p>
      <p id="titulo"></p> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Hasta aquí llegué no consigo grabar la respuesta en variables.

lo intenté hacer como me dijo el compañero en su respuesta pero no hacia nada....

Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Pero ¿cuál es el código Ajax con el que manejas la respuesta?

Comment: he probado variosahora los pongo editando la consulta.... graciassss

Answer (score 0):

No te es necesario el archivo JSON. Con el **echo** que haces en PHP te vale.

```php
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM gastos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"); 
$linea = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $id=$row['id'];
    $importe=$row['importe'];
    $concepto=$row['concepto'];
    $fecha=$row['fecha'];



    $linea[] = array('id'=> $id, 'importe'=> $importe, 'concepto'=> $concepto, 'fecha'=> $fecha);

}

$json_string = json_encode($linea);
echo $json_string;

?>
```

Ahora sólo necesitas hacer una petición en AJAX en tu código JavaScript.

```
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse( this.responseText );
            consolé.log( response );
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "tu-script.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Con el JavaScript obtienes lo que se imprime en el archivo PHP, pasas el resultado a JSON y ya puedes trabajar con el array del resultado en tu consulta.

Comment: Nada... así no hace nada de nada, no me devuelve nada en la consola. :(  pero al abrir el php lo veo... incluso el archivo json que crea estan los datos. ME tiene bastante loco esto, seguro q luego es una chorrada que hago mal...

Comment: Disculpame si es mucho morro, pero podrías probarlo a ver si a ti te funciona? el enlace con el codigo php tal cual lo has pasado tu es: https://pruebasxibo.000webhostapp.com/pruebajson3.php  miles de gracias!

Comment: Manu muchisimas gracias! al final funciona perfecto... lo que no sabia era completar el codigo bien... eso sí solo me funciona en el servidor... estaba probandolo en jsbin... y ahi nada de nada!!!!